# retrying connection to the node - java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: ethereum, listener, indexer

I am trying to indexing rarible mainnet logs, While deploy listeners, unknown host exception error occurs, retrying connection to the node and log also not reflect in db.

[image: screenshot]